# Love, relations are mere lies, go study boy this is your time

Tags: situation

A wise old man once said the above lines when he came to know about one incident.

The incident is as follows.

A man and a woman living in a city on the same street fell in love. Both happily married on the 15th August 2000. Both enjoyed their lives. No one cheated. Both loved their better halves more than anything: more than money, house, or insurance amount. Now as we know, a bad day comes (the law of nature I guess).

One day on 2nd Sep 2020, both were walking on one street. The man got a heart attack. He fell down calling for help. The woman got afraid, stopped for a second, and saw other people coming and helping. But she herself doesn't give a helping hand. She's a little shocked but she keeps on moving. Only other people  help the man and save him.

After knowing the situation the old wise man said this line also: "We should try our best to help others and such a woman is just pathetic".

I just want to tell you the old man is not that wise, he gave his decision without knowing the woman's side. I talked to her and she said if no one else would have come she surely would have helped, but she was already shocked and others also came anyways. She kept on walking to get work at the bakery: customers were waiting and she was late at that day.

Why didn't she stop?

> My answer is simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because...

> They are not related in anyway.

> A man and a woman living in a city , in the same street fell in love,
> both happily married on 15th August 2000 , both enjoyed their lifes,
> no one cheated, both loved their better halves more than anything
> ,more than money , house ,insurance amount :), now as we know bad day
> comes,(The law of nature I guess) .

> They are married to different people which they met on the same street.